# Is this a elliptical construction?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, ellipsis

> "She'd like to think that I'm cruel but she knows that's a lie **for** I would be no more than a tool if I allowed her to cry all over me"

After that *for* is there any omitted term?

For example, could I rewrite that sentence this way:

> "She'd like to think that I'm cruel but she knows that's a lie **for** (herself)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing omitted. "For" in this context means "because". The last definition at [this link](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/for) explains it really well.

> The reason she knows that's a lie is *because* I would be no more than a tool if I allowed her to cry all over me.

Comment: And it would have been clearer if the author had put a comma before "for", to indicate that it introduces a clause, rather than leaving the "for" dangling awkwardly between "lie" and "I".